# In swift, is there a way to add new data from second Realm bundle, without overwriting any existing data in the current Default Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, bundle, overwrite

Upon initial load of the app, the Bundled Realm (Realm1) is copied to the documents folder. Now that the bundled realm is set as the default realm, I am able update the bool property so that the table view can show marked and unmarked cells. However I am looking for a way to bundle a second realm (Realm2) with a later update, that will add new data to the existing default realm, but without overwriting the current default realm. I am currently working in swift 5 and Xcode 11.1, if that is helpful.

So far the only thing that I can think of is adding block of code to add new entries to the default realm. First the view will check to see what the count is of the realm, and if the count is the same as the original bundle, then it will add new data, if the count is equal to the initial bundle plus the new entries, then it will not add the new data again. I was hoping for a simpler solution that is cleaner in my opinion.

Ideally the end result would be a way to update the existing default realm, without overwriting the already edited content. Although I am rather new to using realm, any help in pointing me in the right direction for a solution would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Attached below is the current code I have implemented to load the default realm from the bundle.

```swift
    let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "preloadedData", ofType: "realm")!
            let defaultPath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!.path
            let fileManager = FileManager.default

    //        Copy Realm on initial launch
            if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: defaultPath){
                do {
                    try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: bundlePath, toPath: defaultPath)
                    print("Realm was copied")
                } catch {
                    print("Realm was not coppied \(error)")
                }
            }
            return true
```

Comment: You can use multiple realms, and if they are being kept in the same folder they won't overwrite. Additionally, if you want to pull data out of one bundled realm you can use it just a like a realm stored on disk. Read the data from it, and write the data to the other realm. The only requirement here is that all of your realm references are weak so when changing realms, they can be 'disconnected' so you can then access the other realm. Also, you cannot write to bundled realms but that doesn't seem to be the the case here. It's important to include code you've tried here on SO.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion (first time posting). So, I have added the code that I am currently using to copy over the bundled realm and initialize the default realm. My objective is to provide a bundled realm, copy it so that the user can edit the bools, and then be able to update the realm in future updates, without affecting the changes that each individual user made to only the bools . I will look into the primary id feature and see if that gets me where I need to go. thank you for the suggestion. If you have any other ideas on how I can make this possible, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: That objective is a little vague - are you saying you want to copy the bundled realm to disk so it can be modified, then in the future have a different bundled Realm supplied with the app an integrate that newly bundled data into the Realm on disk ensuring the bools the user changed are not modified?

Comment: I would like to be able to bundle data with the app, allow the user to update bools in that data to mark items, and update the remaining data or add new entries in the app with further updates. I guess I am looking for a way for to implement a method to scan the bundled realm file to check for any changes to anything outside of the bools, and update the realm that they can edit in the documents folder with any changes or new entries. I hope that is a little more clear. So yes what you are saying is accurate.

Comment: Just off the top of my head; when you push out a new app release with a new bundled realm, when the app starts, read in all of the bools you are interested in from the existing (old) Realm file. Delete the realm file and replace it with the bundled one and replace the bools with what you read from the original Realm file.

Comment: *Storing the results while the Realm is replaced* is a little tricky because Realm is a live database and the objects stored in Results are 'connected' to the datastore - so *storing the results* doesn't actually make sense in the Realm world. You cannot modify managed Realm objects outside a write. In other words, if you delete a Realm, the Results in your app would be deleted as well, and Realm won't actually let you do that. I am going to add a followup answer as this seems to come up from time to time.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution seems very practical. What would be the best way to store the results while the realm is replaced. I was able to read out all items with a true bool, do I have to now convert it to an array? Is it possible to make this happen automatically after the app version changes, or will this need to happen every time the app launches. Also, How do I "like" your comment as a solution to my problem or something like that? (Sorry, I am rather new to this website)

Comment: I was worried about that happening after I deleted it that the results I have will no longer be there. I agree that my wording on it was a little off. Maybe if I write a temporary realm to store the data that was read, and then restore from the temporary realm. I am unsure so II will await your followup answer and make sure to mark it as a solution. Thanks again for all the responses.

Comment: One note is that you can always create non-managed standalone copies of your realm objects that would not be affected by deleting the realm. See the [standalone Realm object](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#faq-swift-structs) docs. You could grab copies of the objects, delete the old realm and write them to the new realm.

Comment: Well I was able to get the standalone objects, however deleting and replacing the default realm, while restoring the bool properties from the stand alone objects proved to be a bit troublesome. Maybe I am doing something wrong or it just won't workout. I have a different approach for consideration: would it be possible to copy the entire default realm to create a new temporary realm, then copy the the updated bundle to the default realm, followed by checking against the temporary realm to see if the bools need to be adjusted in the new default realm? Or are there limitations I am not aware of?

Comment: I was more thinking more along the lines of replacing the Realm objects with the ones you have standalone copies of - that would restore all of the values of each. Assuming each object has an existing primary key, it would just be a matter of iterating over the non-managed ones (probably stored in an array or results) and write each one to realm; like this `realm.add(cheeseBook, update: .modified)` see [Objects with Primary Keys](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#objects-with-primary-keys)

Comment: That might be my missing link. I don't have a primary key set as of yet (since I just imported the CSV with the realm browser app on Mac). I guess I will have to do a migration to set the primary keys, and then try it again. I did read through the primary key just now, and it looks like it might work, as long as I am able to delete the realm. I might look back at trying to use the realm cocoa converter in app instead, I was having trouble making that work for some reason. Thanks, I will explore and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've created your default Realm on disk, if you want to read data from the bundled one, here's the code

```
    let config = Realm.Configuration(
        // Get the URL to the bundled file
        fileURL: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyBundledData", withExtension: "realm"),
        // Open the file in read-only mode as application bundles are not writeable
        readOnly: true)
    let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
```

and once you've read the data, you can switch back

```
var config = Realm.Configuration()
config.fileURL = config.fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("\(some_realm_name).realm")
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```

as far as not overwriting, ensure your objects use a unique primary key and when they are written, nothing will be overwritten as objects will a unique primary key will be added instead of overwriting.

```
class MyClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var my_primary_id = NSUUID().uuidString
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding an additional answer that's somewhat related to the first but also stands on it's own.

In a nutshell, once Realm connects to a data source, it will continue to use that data source as long as the objects are not released, even if the actual file is deleted.

The way around that is to encapsulate the Realm calls into an autorelease pool so that those objects can be released when the Realm is deleted.

Here’s an example:

This function adds a GameData object to the default.realm file.

```
func addAnObject() {
   autoreleasepool {
      let realm = try! Realm()
      let testData = GameData()
      testData.Scenario = "This is my scenario"
      testData.Id = 1
      try! realm.write {
         realm.add(testData)
      }
   }
}
```

At this point, if you run the addAnObject code, your file will have a GameData object.

```
GameData {
    Id = 1;
    GameDate = (null);
    Scenario = This is my scenario;
    GameStarted = 0;
}
```

Then a function that delete’s the old realm, and copies the bundled realm to it’s place. This works because all of the interaction with Realm was enclosed in an autorelease pool so the objects can be released.

```
func createDefaultRealm() {
   let defaultURL = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!
   let defaultParentURL = defaultURL.deletingLastPathComponent()

   if let bundledRealmURL = self.bundleURL("default") {
      do {
         try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: defaultURL)
         try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: bundledRealmURL, to: defaultURL)
      } catch let error as NSError {
          print(error.localizedDescription)
          return
      }
   }

   let migrationBlock : MigrationBlock = { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
      //handle migration
   }

   Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 18, migrationBlock: migrationBlock)

   print("Your default realm objects: \(try! Realm().objects(GameData.self))")
}

func bundleURL(_ name: String) -> URL? {
    return Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "realm")
}
```

and please note that if you access Realm inside the class but *outside* an autorelease pool, Realm will refuse to 'let go' of it's objects.

Do do NOT do this!!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var realm = try! Realm()
```