# How make local Realm database in swift on physical device?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, local-database

I'm trying to make local database in Realm. I created new project which I add Realm pods.
Then I made data model and saved few data. Then I download data from physical device **Window >Devices and Simulators >Devices** find installed app and Download Container. In the container I found fold Documents with realm files.

[image]

Then I opened default.realm file and started writing my database. After done database I drag and drop that container (which I downloaded) to my project. In Xcode load my database this way **Product >Scheme >Edit Scheme > Application Data** select my database.

During writing app I notice I can only read data from database and if I catch it right I made by mistake Sandbox, and that is reason why a can't write new data.

I tried different way how to save data with CoreData and same result.
I can save data, when app run I downloaded container and checked in SQLite file and inside I found data which I saved in app but then I re-run app SQLite file is empty.

So I would like to ask what to do now. If is different way how to load local database to app or make multi Realms database?
What is the best way to use local database in app where you can CRUD?

Thank you for any help, I am beginner in the developer world and sorry for my English level :).

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Are you trying to include a pre-populated Realm file in your App bundle?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to use pre-filled Realm file.

Comment: That's somewhat covered in the docs [Bundling a Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#bundling-a-realm). Give that a read and try some code and let us know where you get stuck, and we'll take a look.

Comment: I created new project and added Realm with pods, in project I added new model file for Realm, after I done every steps except 2. according to docs and I got this error: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=2 "Unable to open a realm at path '/Users/....': Invalid mnemonic.

Comment: If you're trying to open a file on your device at */Users* you may have missed step #5 where you should be opening the bundled file, not the file on your drive. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58417998/in-swift-is-there-a-way-to-add-new-data-from-second-realm-bundle-without-overw/58455701#58455701) as well.

Comment: I am trying on both on simulator and on device, I inserted your first block of code from your answer into viewController  and same error, (I rewrote Resource name)

Comment: Without showing us the code you're having difficulty with, we are just guessing. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I solved it :). The problem was  in my the pre-populated realm file, I made new one and now it's working. Thank you for help, now I know how use more realm files, with Configuration.